# Proguarding Android Apps - how essential is it (esp in relation to In-App Payments)

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, obfuscation, proguard

I realise this is a loaded question but I'm hoping someone with a deeper understanding of obfuscation and public key security etc. will be able to help - and the issues are wider than just Apps with In App Purchases too, of course, but that's my personal interest at this point.

I once made the mistake of using ProGuard on one of my (free) Android Apps - I say mistake because tracing problems reported by users became and utter and total NIGHTMARE and I soon realised I was gaining nothing and so  I dropped it.

I now have paid Apps and apps with In-App Purchases (using both Amazon and Google Billing Systems) ready for launch and it seems that using Proguard (or a similar alternative) is strongly recommended - but before I step back into that nightmare, is it REALLY essential?

If people want to reverse-engineer my code to remove ads or get Apps 'for free' then they'll do it somehow I'm sure - but I obviously don't want to make things like Billing Systems and people's personal credentials less secure!

The Google Play In-App Billing talks about obfuscating things like the In-App product Public Keys (by storing them in separate bits to make changing them harder) - I guess not Proguarding weakens that further - but is this just my Apps or does it have a wider effect on other people's Apps/customers own personal security?

Basically - I care not 1 jot about pirates because they will do what they do regardless, I certainly don't want to give myself work for just that purpose, but neither do I want to weaken security for other users either!

Anyone clued-up enough on this to comment??

Comment: Generally you should be writing payment processing systems so that a client being compromised doesn't compromise the overall system.

Comment: That's a pretty vague statement - >I< should or the vendors of the Payment Systems should??  I'd remind you that nowhere does it say you 'MUST' use obfuscation - only that it's encouraged...

Comment: Without being familiar with the specifics of those two systems I assume that the public key being compromised wouldn't cause a problem, it just means I could make an app where the funds for the purchase ended up in your account. Things like personal customer data should be stored on a secure server, using standard methods like SSL to encrypt communications. If someone's phone is compromised and they lose 'their' personal data there's not much you can do about it, just make sure it doesn't affect anyone else.

Comment: I assume that changing the key would result in purchases from my App being creditted to someone else (they simply create an App with the same SKUs for sale and gobble-up my cash) - if I had a million customers, I'd worry about that - but I don't :)

Comment: John, to clarify this further — changing the key would only allow them to impersonate the Google server (to _your_ specific app) so that they can fake IAP signatures and thus pirate the IAPs. The threat you describe (someone stealing your credits by publishing a pirated app from another account) is very unlikely, because (a) people don't generally pay for IAPs in pirated apps and (b) it opens the pirate's real credentials to a potential crime investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProGuard only helps prevent piracy; it does not affect the safety of personal information.

Well-designed payment processing systems (for the public) remain secure even if someone hacks their client (a.k.a. your app). The most someone could do is access paid content without paying, but there's no way for a hacker to compromise other people's apps through the Google or Amazon payment systems.

So, adding Google or Amazon payment processing to an app does not affect the security of the app.

However, if a hacker manages to hack someone else's phone through regular means, they might be able to access the payment information stored in your app. But ProGuard only protects code, not personal information, so it would not prevent this sort of hack either.

Comment: Yes, and it's just obfuscation. If you decompile it, you get the actual source code back, of course with nonsense class, method and variable names. It's still readable, searchable and usable though.

Comment: One answer and a follow-up comment which are fantastically useful - thanks for those!!